# How i start a function in main activity when intent service stop?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I create an application with alarm service and play an alarm mp3 file when the user set up a Timepicker.Alarm service class start from broadcast receiver with alarm manager...I want when stop alarm service return to main activity and start a function for send data with bluetooth.How i can do this?I try this with second receiver but no work...

```
public class AlarmService extends IntentService {


public String response="";

MediaPlayer mPlayer;

  public AlarmService() {
    super("AlarmService");
  }

  // Will be called asynchronously be Android
  @Override
  protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

      mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(AlarmService.this, R.raw.alarm);
      mPlayer.start();


       String data="start";
       Intent intentsend=new Intent("update");//Send data to update UI
       intentsend.putExtra( "Alarmdata",data);
       sendBroadcast(intentsend);

  }
```

and in main activity....

```
    @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

     updateReceiver=new BroadcastReceiver() {
          @Override
          public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intentsend) {
              //get extras, do some stuff
            String data1 = intentsend.getStringExtra("Alarmdata");
            if(data1=="start"){
            String data2="1";

         Toast.makeText(context, "Test updateReceiver!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            try {
                sendData(data2);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }

          }
      };
      IntentFilter updateIntentFilter=new IntentFilter("update");
      registerReceiver(updateReceiver, updateIntentFilter);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Handler and Messaging to achieve what you want a simple example would be this.

First send a message that your work has completed

```
Message message = new Message();
    message.getData().putString("text",
            "exitedtask");
    Messenger messenger = new Messenger(
            completionHander);
    try {
        messenger.send(message);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Then use a Handler to handle what should happen

```
protected Handler completionHander = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            if (msg.getData().getString("text")
                    .equalsIgnoreCase("exitedtask")) {
                //do you work here
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: How i declared completionHandler?I have error...inside service...i put the first piece of code...